# Loop through a list of sub urls from excel in selenium(URL Building)

Tags: python-2.7, url, selenium-webdriver, xlrd

I'm trying to iterate though a list of url's which are saved in a excel file. the url is somethiing like www.xyz.com/variable . xyz.com is always fixed but variables are stored in a excel file which needs to be iterated.

Here's what i have been trying:

```
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook("people.xlsx")
worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
url_tt= xyz.com

for current_row in range(worksheet.nrows):
    caseid = worksheet.row(current_row)[0]

url_final = url_tt + caseid 
driver.get("url_final")
```

Answer (score 0):

`caseid` is an object of type [Cell](http://www.lexicon.net/sjmachin/xlrd.html#xlrd.Cell-class). Try `caseid.value` to get its value as a string instead.